# Problems with Perl eval

Tags: perl, eval

I have the following code, which will set the value of `$mystring` by reading from a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my $mystring1 = "vault.\$_[0].org/\$_[1].\$_[2]/os/\$_[4]";
my $mystring2 = "vault.$_[0].org/$_[1].$_[2]/os/$_[4]";

&myfunc ("A1", "b2", "C3", "d4");

sub myfunc {

    print Dumper(\@_);

    print ("Before=$mystring1\n");
    my $test = eval($mystring1);
    print ("test=$test\n");

    print ("Before=$mystring2\n");
    $test = eval($mystring2);
    print ("test=$test\n");
}
```

However, the following output is produced:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in concatenation (.) or string at ./t.pl line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./t.pl line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./t.pl line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./t.pl line 7.
$VAR1 = [
          'A1',
          'b2',
          'C3',
          'd4'
        ];
Before=vault.$_[0].org/$_[1].$_[2]/os/$_[4]
Use of uninitialized value $test in concatenation (.) or string at ./t.pl line 15.
test=
Before=vault..org/./os/
Use of uninitialized value $test in concatenation (.) or string at ./t.pl line 18.
test=
```

What is causing the issues and how can I achieve the following?

```
test=vault.A1.org/b2.C3/os/d4
```

How would I use `eval` or create a subroutine to get this to work?

Comment: Using `eval` like this is like using a chain saw to trim your fingernails.

Answer (score 5):

I would not use `eval`. In general it should be avoided unless absolutely necessary due to the security implications linked to it. In your case it's probably a bad idea as you say

> The value of mystring is set in a file being read in

Which means that your `eval` call could execute arbitrary user input... a **bad** idea!

Use [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $mystring1="vault.%s.org/%s.%s/os/%s";

myfunc ("A1", "b2", "C3", "d4");

sub myfunc {
    print Dumper(\@_);
    my $test = sprintf $mystring1, @_;
    print ("test=$test\n");
}
```

A simple solution that does everything you require.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using eval correctly. It tries to execute some statement, like `vault..`, which results in an error (inspect `$@` after `eval`).

This works as expected, because the quotes make it evaluate as a string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $mystring1 = '"vault.$_[0].org/$_[1].$_[2]/os/$_[3]"';

&myfunc("A1", "b2", "C3", "d4");

sub myfunc {
    print Dumper(\@_);
    print("Before=$mystring1\n");
    my $test = eval($mystring1);
    print("test=$test\n");
}
```

But using eval [for this particular task] doesn't make any sense.